# Prevent Spring Boot from registering a servlet filter

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot WebMVC application, and a bean that inherits from AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter which I am explicitly adding to a specific spot in the Spring Security filter chain. My Spring Security configuration looks like this:

```
<http pattern="/rest/**">
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
  <http-basic/>
  <custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthenticationFilter"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="preAuthenticationFilter" class="a.b.PreAuthenticationFilter">
  <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="customAuthenticationManager"/>
</beans:bean>
```

The security configuration works. The problem is, because the PreAuthenticationFilter class inherits from AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter, Spring Boot treats it as a general purpose servlet filter and is adding it to the servlet filter chain for all requests. I don't want this filter to be part of the filter chain for all requests. I only want it to be part of the specific Spring Security filter chain that I've configured. Is there a way to prevent Spring Boot from automatically adding the preAuthenticationFilter bean to the filter chain?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

By default Spring Boot creates a `FilterRegistrationBean` for every `Filter` in the application context for which a `FilterRegistrationBean` doesn't already exist. This allows you to take control of the registration process, including disabling registration, by declaring your own `FilterRegistrationBean` for the `Filter`. For your `PreAuthenticationFilter` the required configuration would look like this:

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean registration(PreAuthenticationFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registration.setEnabled(false);
    return registration;
}
```

You may also be interested in [this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2173) which discusses how to disable the automatic registration of `Filter` and `Servlet` beans.

Comment: filter working even after registration.setEnabled(false);

Comment: @Nandhu In that case I'd recommend asking a question of your own with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve).

Comment: @Nandhu what did you end up doing? I am facing same issue, even after setEnabled(false); filter is registering.

Comment: occur an error `No qualifying bean of type 'XxxFilter' available`

Answer (score 11):

If you want to unregister all filters at one time here's my trick:

```
public class DefaultFiltersBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory bf)
            throws BeansException {
        DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) bf;

        Arrays.stream(beanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(javax.servlet.Filter.class))
                .forEach(name -> {

                    BeanDefinition definition = BeanDefinitionBuilder
                            .genericBeanDefinition(FilterRegistrationBean.class)
                            .setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
                            .addConstructorArgReference(name)
                            .addConstructorArgValue(new ServletRegistrationBean[]{})
                            .addPropertyValue("enabled", false)
                            .getBeanDefinition();

                    beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(name + "FilterRegistrationBean",
                            definition);
                });
    }
}
```

A bit more about this technique - [here](http://dimafeng.com/2015/11/27/dynamic-bean-definition/).

Comment: This has worked well in our app that declared a _lot_ of Filter beans to be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to disable registering 2 filters(like i did), include a name for the bean(so that they do not override):

```
@Bean(name = "filterRegistrationBean1")
public FilterRegistrationBean<YourFilter1> registration(YourFilter1 f1) {
    FilterRegistrationBean<YourFilter1> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(f1);
    registration.setEnabled(false);
    return registration;
}

@Bean(name = "filterRegistrationBean2")
public FilterRegistrationBean<YourFilter2> registration(YourFilter2 f2) {
    FilterRegistrationBean<YourFilter2> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(f2);
    registration.setEnabled(false);
    return registration;
}
```

#### [Bonus](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/):

The fact that all filters internal to Spring Security are unknown to the container is important, especially in a Spring Boot application, where, by default, all @Beans of type Filter are registered automatically with the container. So if you want to add a custom filter to the security chain, you need to either not make it be a @Bean or wrap it in a FilterRegistrationBean that explicitly disables the container registration.

Answer (score 0):

I use aop to do that, use around pointcut to joincut your filter, manully invode
`filterChain.doFilter(request, response)`

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AspectDemo {

    @Around(value = "com.xxx.pointcut01()")
    public void around01(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("[Aspect-around01] start");

        ServletRequest request = (ServletRequest)Arrays.asList(
                ((MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint) joinPoint).getArgs()
        ).get(0);

        ServletResponse response = (ServletResponse)Arrays.asList(
                ((MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint) joinPoint).getArgs()
        ).get(1);


        FilterChain filterChain = (FilterChain)Arrays.asList(
                ((MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint) joinPoint).getArgs()
        ).get(2);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

        //do not execute origin doFilter() method
        //joinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println("[Aspect-around01] end");

    }

}
```