# SpringSecurity: FilterChainProxy: VirtualFilterChain --> What populates the originalChain?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm writing a new spring security configuration. I need to import some other company libraries with their own configuration/filters. Every filter with an @Component/@Bean annotation are appearing in the "originalChain" property of the FilterChainProxy and being run on requests. I've searched documentation and can't figure out what the originalChain property is, why its there, what determines the filters that go there etc. I want to stop the unused filters from being run.

One article described it as " originalChain represents the native filter chain, that is, Web Filter" I haven't been able to figure out what that means.

What is the originalChain?

Comment: I'm not sure what code would be useful here but I can post anything thats needed.

Answer (score 0):

Every Servlet application can have multiple `Filter` implementations executing before reaching the actual `Servlet`. And the big picture is something like this:

[image: Servlet Filter Chain representation]

Spring provides a Filter implementation named [DelegatingFilterProxy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) that allows bridging between the Servlet container’s lifecycle and Spring’s `ApplicationContext`. The Servlet container allows registering Filters using its own standards, but it is not aware of Spring defined Beans. `DelegatingFilterProxy` can be registered via standard Servlet container mechanisms, but delegate all the work to a Spring Bean that implements Filter.

[image: DelagatingFilterProxy overview]

With this picture in mind, we can say that the `DelegatingFilterProxy` is an approach that Spring MVC uses to use its own standards when registering filters.

When you expose a Spring Bean that implements `Filter`, it will get registered inside the `DelegatingFilterProxy`.

`FilterChainProxy` is a special `Filter` provided by Spring Security that allows delegating to many Filter instances through `SecurityFilterChain`. Since `FilterChainProxy` is a **Bean**, it is typically wrapped in the `DelegatingFilterProxy`.

[image: FilterChainProxy and SecurityFilterChain]

You can see that this hypothetical picture above has the `FilterChainProxy` as a second filter in the **Filter Chain** (the dashed box). Once the `FilterChainProxy` is done processing its `SecurityFilterChain` filters, it will call the `originalChain` (dashed box) to resume the processing of the remaining filters, in the above scenario, Filter2.

There's also a great explanation in the [Spring Security reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-architecture) where I took most of the resources present in this text.

If you want to prevent a `Filter` to be registered by Spring, you can refer to this [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421966/prevent-spring-boot-from-registering-a-servlet-filter/28428154#28428154).

Comment: Actually, the answer is correct. I had the same issue and just by going through it it helped me solve it. Maybe it's too detailed, but it helped.