# How to use cross context in spring mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have two spring web mvc application app1 and app2.
In app1, I am using jstl import tag to call app2 controller.

```
<c:import context="/app2" url="/req/testUrl"/>
```

This will return some meta tag and javascript.

When I am running app1 jsp its throwing exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncUtils.getAsyncManager(WebAsyncUtils.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:916)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:816)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
```

Spring jars included in both application. I can't keep it in shared folder.
I looked into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128150/spring-and-cross-context-webasyncmanager-cannot-be-cast-to-webasyncmanager) but I did't find answer.

Please help me !